# I added a Like model but I don't know how to increase the number of like

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I created a Blog app, and i want to add a Like button to each post in the Blog, how can i do this ?
how can i make this happen in view and the template ?

the models:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

the view:

```
def viewPhoto(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'photo': photo, 'post': post })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other to use the like functionality you do something like this, but i hope you know how to work the frontend part, in your html?

```
def like(request, pk):
    post = Photo.objects.get(pk=pk)
    liked= False
    like = Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post)
    if like:
        like.delete()
    else:
        liked = True
        Like.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
    resp = {
        'liked':liked
    }
    response = json.dumps(resp)
    return redirect('') #  redirect to any url after the object has  been liked
    return HttpResponse(response,content_type = "application/json")
```

You would need to put the liked object in any view that would prefer to have the like functionality:

```
def viewPhoto(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)
    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)
    liked = [i for i in Photo.objects.all() if Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=i)] 
    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'photo': photo, 'post': post ,'liked':liked})
```

Html template this is just to give you an idea on how to do that in your html , since i don't no what type of script or css you are using. so the button might not look like a thumb in your case.

```
 <button class="btn btn-white mr-3 like" id="{{ post.id }}">
 {% if post in liked %}
 <a href="{% url 'blog:like' post.pk %}" id="likebtn{{ post.pk }}"  
            class="flex items-center space-x-2">
 <div> Unlike</div>
 </a>
    {% else %}
<a href="{% url 'blog:like' post.pk %}" id="likebtn{{ post.pk }}" class="flex items-center space-x-2">                                 
 <div>Like</div>
     </a>
    {% endif %}
   </button>
```

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: id, post, post_id, user, user_id. When I enter viewphoto template

Comment: I made the correction  have a look, and use the code again ! the exception came from the username=request.user instead it should be user=request.user  in both the like view and the viewPhoto , hopefully it should work now!

Comment: yes, it's working fine sir, Thank you so much